# Embed google map using longitude and latitude

Tags: google-maps

I would like to embed Google Map into my website, and I'm passing over 2 parameters, "longtitude" and "latitude".

Any possible way the map will change according to the longitude and latitude I sent in?
For example, I put in 
3.1019924,101.4804983 and click on "Search map" on maps.google.com
I will get the location and the embed code.

How can I do it in a way I have already embed the map, just passing in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you already have the Google Maps javascript Google Maps object in your page, so you just need to center the map given a location.

To do this you need to call the *panTo* method on your [google.maps.Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object.  You pass a [google.maps.LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) object as a parameter and it will center the map on that location:

```
yourMap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Google API.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/